# Why is "mutableStateOf" used instead of "remember" in ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In a ViewModel, `remember` isn't used, but `mutable...`is used:

```kotlin
class CustomViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // ...
    var myDeckList = mutableStateListOf<Deck>()
    // ...
}
```

Does `ViewModel` have a delegated responsibility similar to what `remember` provides?

If so, why is `mutable...` not delegated?

Comment: Where do you find the examples? Can you link me some? I was going through the wrong examples the last couple of days.

Answer (score 12):

`remember` is used to preserve state across recompositions. If we are storing state inside ViewModel, it will automatically survive recompositions because it's outside the composition tree.

`mutableStateOf` serves a different purpose. It creates a `MutableState` which is:

> A mutable value holder where reads to the [value] property during the execution of a [Composable] function, the current [RecomposeScope] will be subscribed to changes of that value. When the [value] property is written to and changed, a recomposition of any subscribed [RecomposeScope]s will be scheduled.

It sets up an observer pattern (like a LiveData, StateFlow, etc.) where writes to the value inform the readers about the value change. So ViewModel has nothing to do with this observer pattern and that's why you still need to use `mutable...` functions in your ViewModel.

The `mutableStateListOf` that you have used in you question works along the same lines. It creates a `SnapshotStateList` which is a type of `MutableList` that is observable and can be snapshot.

Comment: Can you link me to some good examples? I was going through the wrong examples for the last couple of days.

Comment: You can checkout the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state). It has good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a remember{} function inside a viewModel.
It's just simply not possible since remember{} functions can be only called inside composable contexts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).